# What is it called when authors lend citation to one another?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Citation is one metric of researchers. That is why some of them lend citation to one another. For example, A writes a paper and cites B's work in it, providing that B does the same for A.

Is there any word for such academic misconduct? I can think of "citation exchange", but I couldn't find any reference about it.

Comment: "You scratch my back ...."

Comment: But seriously, that would be "mutual citation" or "cross citation" (only if the references are to the same articles, not just the authors.) "... judges more often cite those judges who cite them frequently, which suggests the presence of mutual citation clubs." https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/588263?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: What you just described is not *misconduct* if each is using a legitimate citation.

Comment: Reciprocation. Or mutual... something or other... point is: there isn't a specific term, but this is entirely normal in some contexts and completely unacceptable in others. You'd need to provide an example sentence to clarify the intent, motivations, etc.

Comment: @JasonBassford It's recognized as a malpractice. No matter if the citation itself is legitimate or not. https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/120742/3985

Comment: @jimm101 https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/120742/3985

Comment: This question has been already dealt with on another SE site: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/120742/3985

Answer (score 2):

**"logrolling"**

The term is better known in other fields such as politics and book reviewing/criticism (politicians mutually supporting each other's bills; authors mutually reviewing books such that A favourably reviews B's book and B favourably review's A's book). Wikipedia says, "In an academic context, the Nuttall Encyclopedia describes logrolling as 'mutual praise by authors of each other's work'."

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logrolling
- https://www.dictionary.com/browse/logrolling

(According to Wikipedia, the term originates in people helping each other move heavy firewood.)

Comment: Too broad; same as back-scratching I already noted above.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the best suggestions for what I was looking for:

> 1. Citation Circles
> 2. Citation Cartels
> 3. Citation Rings

Thanks to helps from [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/120742/what-is-it-called-when-authors-trade-citations?noredirect=1#comment319725_120742).